# Group dictionary by key in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to implement a groupBy functionality where all the numbers of a nested list are grouped. My code so far:

```
struct MyClass {
    var numbers: [Int]
    ...
}

var dict: [String : MyClass] = ...
let numbers = dict
   .filter{ $0.0.containsString(searchString) }
   .flatMap{ $0.1.numbers }
```

This yields me an `Array` of `Int`s. However I'd like to have a dictionary [Int : Int] with each unique number and the count of its occurence. So for example:

```
[1,2,3,4,1,2,2,1]
```

should be:

```
[1 : 2, 2 : 3, 3 : 1, 4 : 1]
```

I know there's a `groupBy` operator, but Swift doesn't seem to have one. I've tried with `reduce`:

```
func reducer(accumulator: [Int: Int], num: Int) -> [Int : Int] {
    var acc = accumulator
    acc[num]! += 1
    return acc
}

filtered.reduce([:], combine: reducer)
```

But it crashes when I want to run it. Not sure why, I get a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Ups, yeah, meant dictionary.

Comment: It would be helpful if the code could be copied and pasted.

Comment: What do you mean copied and pasted?

Comment: I think that @ryantxr means having a *reproducible and testable* example, like the one [I did for myself](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOwWtxGnQyVOr5b-sX9I_lSfo4eG4OGj6VE) in a Playground.

Comment: If possible, I would recommend to avoid creating dictionaries using `reduce`.

Comment: I pasted your code in playground and had to "fix" several issues before it would run.  The "..." for example. And the variable `filtered` does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,1,2,2,1]
var results = [Int: Int]()

Set(numbers).forEach { number in results[number] = numbers.filter { $0 == number }.count }

print(results) // [2: 3, 3: 1, 1: 3, 4: 1]
```

Actually I'm not very sure if this is what you want. I just looked at your examples.

Using `NSCountedSet`:

```
var objects = [1,2,3,4,1,2,2,1]
let uniques = NSCountedSet(array: objects)
uniques.forEach { results[$0 as! Int] = uniques.countForObject($0) }

print(results) // [2: 3, 3: 1, 1: 3, 4: 1]
```

Comment: This is brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect the crash to be ocurring on this line:

```
acc[num]! += 1
```

The first time this is called for a number, the entry doesn't exist in the dictionary yet so `acc[num]` is `nil`. Forcefully unwrapping it would cause a crash.

Not sure if this is the best solution but you can simple check for this case:

```
if (acc[num]) {
    acc[num]! += 1
} else {
    acc[num] = 1
}
```

Cleaner code from @vacawama in the comments:

```
acc[num] = (acc[num] ?? 0) + 1
```

Comment: @Swalker not an issue, glad I can help. :] Welcome to SO!

Comment: `acc[num] = (acc[num] ?? 0) + 1`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension to Array that does what you're asking:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
  var grouped: [Element:Int] {
    var dict = [Element:Int]()
    self.forEach { dict[$0] = (dict[$0] ?? 0) + 1 }
    return dict
  }
}
```

The key is the closure: `{ dict[$0] = (dict[$0] ?? 0) + 1 }`.

It takes the current value in the array, tests to see if it's a key in the dictionary, returns the value for that key if it exists or 0 if it doesn't, then adds one and sets the key:value to be the pair of the current value and occurrences so far.

Example use:

```
[1,2,3,4,1,2,2,1].grouped // => [2: 3, 3: 1, 1: 3, 4: 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
if let _ = acc.indexForKey(num) {
    acc[num]! += 1
}
else {
    acc[num] = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of unclear what you're asking for, but here's a function that will take an array of ints and return a dictionary with the number as the key, and the count as the value:

```
func getDictionaryOfCounts(accumulator: [Int]) -> [Int : Int] {
    var countingDictionary: [Int : Int] = [:]
    accumulator.forEach { (value) in
        if countingDictionary[value] != nil {
            countingDictionary[value]! += 1
        }
        else{
            countingDictionary[value] = 1
        }
    }
    return countingDictionary
}
```